# QT signal-slot not received

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am trying to connect a signal from a second QMainWindow to the mainwindow. It doesn't say anything about a problem connection when the program is launched, but It doesn't work. I am not very familiar with C++ and Qt so maybe is something simple.

My code consists on a Mainwindow used as a SCADA with Start, stop, On, off buttons. In the second qmainwindow I created a terminal where you can type, start,stop... There, I would like to emit a signal to my MainWindow which is in charge of controlling the multiple threads and windows. The problem is that I cannot connect to my slot. I present here a simple overview of this two pieces of code.

Terminal. h

```
#ifndef TERMINAL__H
#define TERMINAL__H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QObject>

namespace Ui {
class Terminal_;
}

class Terminal_ : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Terminal_(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Terminal_();

signals:
    void turnonPLC_terminal();

public slots:
    void newline();

private:
    Ui::Terminal_ *ui;
    QTextEdit* mTerminal;
    QLineEdit* mInput;

};

#endif // TERMINAL__H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "terminal_.h"
#include "terminal_help.h"


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    Terminal_ *terminal;


public slots:
    void turnon_terminal();

private:

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;



};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "terminal_.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    terminal = new Terminal_(this);
    connect(terminal, SIGNAL(turnonPLC_terminal()), this, SLOT(turnon_terminal()));


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::turnon_terminal(){
    turnonPLC=1;
}
```

terminal_.cpp

```
#include "terminal_.h"
#include "ui_terminal_.h"

#include <QDockWidget>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLineEdit>

QString on=("on");

Terminal_::Terminal_(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Terminal_)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mTerminal = new QTextEdit();
    setCentralWidget(mTerminal);
    mInput = new  QLineEdit();

    QDockWidget* qdw = new QDockWidget;
    qdw->setWidget(mInput);
    addDockWidget(Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea, qdw);
    connect (mInput, SIGNAL(returnPressed()),
             this, SLOT(newline()));

}

Terminal_::~Terminal_()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Terminal_::newline(){
    QString command = mInput->text();
    if (command==on){
    emit turnonPLC_terminal();
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your `command==on` variable equals `on`? Hm, what is `on` by the way? I bet this signal just is not emitted. Did you try to debug your application?

Comment: Related to what @VictorPolevoy said: you're taking a `QString` from the `QLineEdit` control, so shouldn't the `if` statement be `if (command == "on")`?

Comment: Also, you're connecting a signal from a class member to a slot in the same class; it sounded like you wanted to connect a signal from one class to a slot in a different class.

Comment: Sorry, I removed that when I was reducing the code, but I had declared QString=("on").  My terminal has multiple commands and all of them are working well. Only the signal is failing, and it is what Carlton pointed out. I want to connect from one class to another slot in another class...Yes sure, that's the reason.. I am not sure how to solve it but I guess I will find something on internet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The signal-slots part in the code works perfectly. (compiled and tested with some small modifications)
After entering "on" (not On as written in question) 
`Terminal_::newline()` slot called, `turnonPLC_terminal()` is fired and finally
`void MainWindow::turnon_terminal()` is called.

However, there are some small details the header file is called terminal_.h, not Terminal.h `turnonPLC` is not defined. terminal is created by not displayed (no show-call).

I guess, there are simply some many small logic errors. Try to use debugger or trace the chain of expected calls with qDebug.

Comment: Sorry but these small mistakes are mainly because my project contains 20 files for all my windows and threads...so when reducing it I forget like declaring here the variable turnonPLC, but for my code is working. And the same for the terminal which is being displayed fine. I tried changing the name of my library but still is not working... I have been with this problem two days and I have decided to jump it. I share a variable from my terminal_.cpp to another thread, and from there  I send the signal. And I've solved it like 5 minutes ago, it is not ideal but it works. Thanks a lot ;)